# Help! My Uniform has Sha'atnez!

Tags: halacha, clothing, shaatnez

Note: this question is not lema'aseh. If it applies to you, please consult a competent halachic authority.

Suppose someone is part of a uniformed service. They are issued a uniform which, when checked, contains sha'atnez. They request a replacement and find that that too contains sha'atnez.

In short, if one is required to wear a uniform which will certainly contain sha'atnez, what should one do?

Comment: What are the consequences for not wearing the uniform? Can he quit? Do you have the same question about a job that, for example requires him to eat non-kosher? If not, why not? Consider editing this in to clarify.

Comment: See Gemara brachot 19b R`Judah said in the name of Rab: If one finds mixed kinds(3) in his garment, he takes it off even in the street.

What is the reason?

[It says]: There is no wisdom nor understanding nor counsel against the Lord;(4) wherever a profanation of God's name is involved no respect is paid to a teacher.

Comment: I recall a story about a Jewish soldier who's winter uniform contained sha'atnez and therefore wore his summer uniform in the freezing European winters.

Comment: @LN6595, wouldn't he be oveir venishmarten et nafshoteichem then?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt Or V'chai bahem? It must be that the soldier gauged that it would not be life-threatening. One is often permitted to take a risk for the sake of a mitzvah - see Shut Mimaamakim.

Comment: @LN6595, at least the way you told it, it seems like a life-threatening situation.

Answer (score 6):

Since the question is not lima'aseh, I'll give an answer that is not lima'aseh.

Not every placing of clothing upon one's body is called wearing clothes and in some situations will actually be allowed.

See Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah siman 301 siff 6 with Shach #8 at length where he discusses in depth various situations and laws in that siman with the running explanation that only when intending to actually wear the clothes is it assur, whereas placing them upon oneself as if wearing them, but not intending to wear them is allowed as a davar she'eino miskaven.

Now, here is the fun part. Head over to Orach Chaim siman 10 and look in the second to last Biur Halacha. He brings one svara to allow a certain type of scarf to be worn without Tzitzis being that it is not worn to be clothing but rather it is just worn for honor. He has other svaras he mentions too, but this idea that something worn only for honor is not classified as a real wearing might apply to a uniform as well.

A question on that Biur Halacha which would have ramifications to this discussion is that earlier in the siman the Shulchan Aruch discussed a Kapha and it's apparent necessity to have Tzitzis. The Maharik who is the source of that idea definitely believed the Kapha was worn as a sign of honor. That same Maharik is brought in the Ramma in Yoreh Deah 178 where we see this point quite clearly.